# How to receive a Knock Back when the player touched the enemy

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics, platformer

I'm still new to C#, making my 2D game atm and my problem is how can I give my player a Knock Back when it touches the enemy. How to add it with this code?

```
public int health; 

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        health -= 20;
        //Check for death 
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you move your player currently?

Comment: It's a 2D platformer. It's like Super Mario. :D

Comment: What I'm looking for here is the code that moves your player. There are many ways to code a 2D platformer, and integrating knockback into each will look a little different.

Comment: Here is the code script of the movement of the player:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQ4SZabzIp7c5JFWj8kUGscib7EYaNWDLfPJ0ngBpDp7aOE7iSjbgI7cxlgc4d3UMr-sY-FOjSOhVOU/pub

Comment: If it's important to understand your question, then add the code to your question using the "Edit" link. Assume that any document hosted on another site will not be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share some code which will help you out:

```
 public float force = 5;
 public ForceMode forceMode = ForceMode.Impulse;

 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
 {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision");
        health -= 20;
        //Check for death 
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate Angle Between the collision point and the player
            ContactPoint2D contactPoint = collision.GetContact(0);
            Vector2 playerPosition = transform.position;
            Vector2 dir = contactPoint.point - playerPosition;

            // We then get the opposite (-Vector3) and normalize it
            dir = -dir.normalized;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().inertia = 0;

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
            //If the problme is not resolved then lock controle key. "playerControles" is a public static boolean which you have declare in the player controller script with true. then in this script you have to enable it or disable it.like
            playerControlerScript.playerControles = false; //if its true player input buttons will work and vice versa.
            Invoke("EnablePlayerControles", 0.5f); //if then amount of time is long then reduce it to the value you want.

            //Also in your player controller script wrap the inputs inside if condition like this if(playerControles){//input/inputs code}.
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

            // And finally we add force in the direction of dir and multiply it by force. 
            // This will push back the player
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(dir * force, forceMode);
        }
    }
}

private void EnablePlayerControles()
{
   playerControlerScript.playerControles = true;
}
```

> Play with force amount and force mode to achieve the effect you want.

I hope this will help.

Comment: for some reason, I am having a problem with that code you gave to me. Like instead of my player getting knockback. it just jumps upwards and sometimes it goes higher. 

Here is the clip of the problem: https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-fe93e23f71a1.gif

Comment: Sorry i am late. but i thinks its due the current velocity. so when player collide with enemy just make player velocity and force to 0 and then apply the knock back force. also i will suggest to lock your control keys so that you can't apply any extra force and just enable the control keys back like after 0.5f sec may be.

Comment: Also i have updated the code. so test it out. I hope it will work.

Comment: I am having a problem with the "playerControles" is that a variable name of a bool?
if so; I am still having the same problem. D:

Comment: yes it is bool but for now forget about it. and remove those lines. and then test the code.

Comment: If it worked then great if not then i will assist you about that bool.

Comment: i have update the instruction inside script. i hop it will help if not please send me the player controller and collision script. with little of explanation about then i will change the script for you. you can get my email address form my profile. just click on Swati and this forward you to my profile.

Comment: Still doesn't work tho but I'll try to give you the playercontroller script, thanks for the help btw! :D

Comment: ok. give me the scripts and i will try to fix them.

Comment: I've change the script and now its works. Either you replace your script with min or copy and past then changes to your script. I showed changes inside the block.

Comment: ehh... for some reason I am having a problem again... xD My knockback won't work when I stay at the left side of the enemy but when I am at the right side the knockback works. What's wrong with this? Here is the clip: https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-2cfcf8c39805.gif

Comment: I tested it again but it work for me. Can you tell me how did you integrated my script to project, have you replace it or have you made the changes to your script.

Comment: I deleted my original script and replace it with yours...